# Inline input buttons are acting like block elements in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

Works as I want it to in Firefox (the `div` containing the `<input />` buttons expands and the buttons are all on the one line).  In Chrome it pops each button on its own line.  This is for a popup in a browser extension, if it's relevant to the problem.

HTML of the popup:

```
<body>
  <div id="popup">
    <input type="button" id="btnTag1" />
    <input type="button" id="btnTag2" />
    <input type="button" id="btnTag3" />
  </div>
  <div id="loader"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
input {
    display: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And the input buttons are programatically changed to inline-block via JS:

```
btn1.style.display = "inline-block";
btn2.style.display = "inline-block";
btn3.style.display = "inline-block";
```

Any ideas why it displays differently in Chrome from Firefox?  I need it to display all in one line (i.e. inline) like it does in Firefox.  Cheers.

Edit: Changed to "inline-block" in the javascript above.  Still displays the same (i.e. vertically instead of horizontally).

Comment: it need to be `inline-block` , show the program which changes the style

Comment: I tried `inline-block`, as I said.  The code that changes it is there as well.

Comment: try to set `#popup{min-width: auto;}`

Comment: @לבנימלכה same result.

Comment: why do not you use `display:flex`??

Comment: are you using position relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It will exactly do what you want. Here is an example:

```css
#popup {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
}

input {
    flex-grow: 1; //this is responsible for letting the buttons fill 
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <input type="button" id="btnTag1" />
  <input type="button" id="btnTag2" />
  <input type="button" id="btnTag3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers mate. Works for both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` to `#popup`

```js
function display(){
document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "flex";

}
```

```css
#popup {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display:none;
}
input {

    border: none;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div id="popup">
    <input type="button" id="btnTag1" value="1"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnTag2" value="1"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnTag3" value="1"/>
  </div>
  <div id="loader"></div>

<button onclick="display()">display</button>
```